# Dashed arrows in pb-diagram

Tags: diagrams, commutative-diagrams

I have a commutative diagram written as a diagram environment defined using the package `pb-diagram`. I'm very satisfied with the appearance of the diagram.

However I need to change some arrows to dashed arrows.

In the `pb-diagram` manual it is stated that the option for the shaft of an arrow are:

```
 ..   |  dotted or dashed arrow shaft
 =    |  double line shaft* (“equals sign”)
 !    |  invisible arrow shaft
```

For instance the command `\arrow{e,..}` should draw a dotted or dashed arrow shaft.

My question is? How can I make sure that the arrow is dashed instead of dotted? In all examples I tried, the arrow becomes dotted.

I would appreciate any suggestions on how to solve this issue in `pb-diagrams`. A minimal example is the following.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pb-diagram}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{diagram}
\node{A} 
    \arrow{e,t,..}{a} 
    \arrow{s,l,..}{c} 
    \arrow{ese,b,1,..}{u}
\node{B}
    \arrow{e,t,..}{b}
\node{C}
    \arrow{s,r}{d} 
    \arrow{wsw,b,1}{v} \\
\node{D}
    \arrow[2]{e,b}{e} 
\node[2]{H}
\end{diagram}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

All dotted arrows should be dashed arrows.

OBS: I'm aware of the existence of a more advanced package called Ti*k*Z, which is more expressive and apparently allows one to have great control of the diagrams. But in this question I'm only interested in how to solve the problem with respect to the package `pb-diagram`, since the diagram, which is pretty large, is already coded and I just need to add some dashed arrows to finalize it. Additionally, I'm having some trouble to install Ti*k*Z on my computer.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please show us a very minimal version of your document which is compilable. We do not want to set up the issue for you just in order to correct one arrow shaft. Thanks.

Comment: I tried to code this for you but I am not used to the `picture` environment which is used by this package. So I am sorry, but I am stuck here. Is your diagram really that big? Maybe it would be easier to post it here and I rewrite it in `tikz-cd` which can do this easily. If you want this in `pb-diagram`, please write a feature request to Paul Burchard

Comment: @LaRiFari thanks for your comments. I added a minimal example above. The diagram is compiling with dotted arrows, but they have to be dashed arrows.

Comment: Contrary to what the manual says, I see no way to produce a dashed arrow with `..`, since it uses `\circle`.

Comment: @egreg and verifying. No, it is not included for sure. I checked the whole code. Adding it was too complicated for me so as I said: I would go with a feature request. The author's address is written on top of his manual.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi The most recent version is dated October 1998.

Comment: @egreg never too late :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here I found the routine in `pb-diagram` that placed dots, named `\dg@dotvector` and made several modifications to it.  I replaced the `\circle` macro that placed each dot with a `\rule`.  However, I needed to have the `\rule` tilted at the proper angle, so I used `\FPdiv` and `\FParctan` and `\FPmul` to calculate the angle tangent, take the arctangent, and convert to degrees.  Then I used `\rotatebox` to angle the aforementioned `\rule` to that angle.

EDITED to take advantage of LaRiFaRi's excellent suggestion, thus allowing the simultaneous use of both dot `..` and dash `--` syntax.  In the following MWE, I show both dot and dash lines (and solid lines) in the graph.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pb-diagram,fp,graphicx}
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\@namedef{dgo@--}{\let\dg@VECTOR=\dg@dashvector}% 
\def\dg@dashvector(#1,#2)#3{% 
   \begingroup
   \dg@XTEMP=#1\relax \dg@YTEMP=#2\relax
   \let\dg@NDOTS=\dg@XEND \let\dg@DOTDIAM=\dg@WEND
   % Find number of dots: make x-spacing be DOTSPACING for arrows
   % of |slope| <= 1, and make y-spacing be DOTSPACING otherwise.
   % Thus, true spacing is never more than 30% off from DOTSPACING.
   \dg@NDOTS=\unitlength \multiply\dg@NDOTS #3\relax
   \dg@ZTEMP=\dg@YTEMP \dg@changesign\dg@YTEMP\dg@ZTEMP
   \ifnum\dg@XTEMP>\z@
      \ifnum\dg@YTEMP>\dg@XTEMP
         \multiply\dg@NDOTS\dg@YTEMP \divide\dg@NDOTS\dg@XTEMP \fi
   \else\ifnum\dg@XTEMP<\z@
      \ifnum\dg@YTEMP>-\dg@XTEMP
         \multiply\dg@NDOTS\dg@YTEMP \divide\dg@NDOTS-\dg@XTEMP \fi
   \fi\fi
   \dg@YTEMP=\dg@ZTEMP
   \divide\dg@NDOTS\dgDOTSPACING
   \ifnum\dg@NDOTS>\z@\else \dg@NDOTS=\@ne \fi
   % Compute increment vector between dots; round to \unitlength's.
   % Use NDOTS not DOTSPACING, since DOTSPACING not exactly obeyed.
   \dg@ZTEMP=\unitlength \multiply\dg@ZTEMP #3\relax
   \divide\dg@ZTEMP\dg@NDOTS
   \ifnum\dg@XTEMP=\z@
      \dg@changesign\dg@ZTEMP\dg@YTEMP \dg@YTEMP=\dg@ZTEMP
   \else
      \dg@changesign\dg@ZTEMP\dg@XTEMP
      \multiply\dg@YTEMP\dg@ZTEMP \divide\dg@YTEMP\dg@XTEMP
      \dg@XTEMP=\dg@ZTEMP
   \fi
   \divide\dg@XTEMP\unitlength \divide\dg@YTEMP\unitlength
   % Draw dotted line with \multiput
   % and arrowhead as zero-length \vector
%%% CALCULATE THE ROTATE ANGLE OF THE DASHED LINE
\ifnum\the\dg@XTEMP>0%
  \FPdiv\arang{\the\dg@YTEMP}{\the\dg@XTEMP}%
  \FParctan\arang{\arang}%
  \FPmul\arang{\arang}{57.295}%
\else
  \def\arang{90}%
\fi
%%%%%
   \begin{picture}(0,0)%
      \dg@DOTDIAM=\dgDOTSIZE \divide\dg@DOTDIAM\unitlength
      \multiput(0,0)(\dg@XTEMP,\dg@YTEMP){\dg@NDOTS}{%
%         \circle*{\dg@DOTDIAM}}% REPLACE THIS LINE WITH THE NEXT
         \smash{\rotatebox{\arang}{\rule{2pt}{.5pt}}}}%
      \multiply\dg@XTEMP\dg@NDOTS \multiply\dg@YTEMP\dg@NDOTS
      \put(\dg@XTEMP,\dg@YTEMP){\vector(#1,#2){0}}%
   \end{picture}%
   \endgroup}%
\makeatother
\begin{equation}
\begin{diagram}
\node{A} 
    \arrow{e,t,..}{a} 
    \arrow{s,l,--}{c} 
    \arrow{ese,b,1,--}{u}
\node{B}
    \arrow{e,t,--}{b}
\node{C}
    \arrow{s,r}{d} 
    \arrow{wsw,b,1}{v} \\
\node{D}
    \arrow[2]{e,b}{e} 
\node[2]{H}
\end{diagram}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

For comparison, here is the default behavior of the routine, without modification:

[image]

Comment: Amazing. This worked perfectly with my file both when compiling it into pdf and into ps files. In the dvi version the diagonals get a bit weird, but again it gets great when converting from dvi to pdf or ps. Many thanks!

Comment: Also thanks to LariFari for the suggestion of using Tikz. But my version of Tikz is old and I'm getting trouble using it with tikz-cd. When I have more time I will reinstall my texlive distribution.

Comment: May I recommend to start your code with `\makeatletter
\@namedef{dgo@--}{\let\dg@VECTOR=\dg@dashvector}%
\def\dg@dashvector(#1,#2)#3{%` giving the possibility to do `\node{A} 
    \arrow{e,t,--}{a} 
    \arrow{s,l,..}{c} `.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi Thank you for the really nice extension.

Answer (score 3):

Just in case you change your mind :-)

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    \begin{tikzcd}[every arrow/.append style={-latex}]
        A
        \arrow[dashed]{r}{a} 
        \arrow[dashed]{d}[swap]{c} 
        \arrow[dashed]{drr}[near start,swap]{u}
        & B
        \arrow[dashed]{r}{b}
        & C
        \arrow{d}{d} 
        \arrow{dll}[near start]{v} \\
        D \arrow{rr}[swap]{e} 
        & 
        & 
        H 
    \end{tikzcd}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]